# Simplify code to nullify too many if-else-statements

Tags: design-patterns

I was trying to design a rewarding system in Java which will reward users based on their current transaction information.
I have to return different reward weights based on the certain criteria the transaction meets.This is the code sample for the class that assigns reward weights.

```
class RewardWeight {

    #condition 1
    public boolean is50thTransactionOfDay(Transaction t){
        //logic to find 50th Transaction
    }

    #condition 2
    public boolean is200thTransactionOfWeek(Transaction t){
        //logic to find 200th Transaction
    }


    #condition 3
    public boolean isTransactionAbove2000(Transaction t){
        //logic goes here
    }

    #condition 4
    public boolean isTransactionRepeated(Transaction t){
        //logic goes here
    }

    public int getRewardWeight(){
        // if condition 1 and condition 2 satisfied return 1
        // if condition 2 and condition 3 satisfied return 2
        // if condition 1 and condition 3 satisfied return 3
        // if condition 3 and condition 4 satisfied return 4
        // if condition 3 and condition 4 satisfied return 8
        // if condition 1 , 2 and 3 satisfied return 5
        // if condition 1 , 2 and 3,4 satisfied return 6
    }
}
```

Is there any way to return different weights as in

> getRewardWeight()

method without having too many if else conditions.
Also , it should be flexible to support any new feature as well.( **such as a new reward criteria** ).

Comment: @g.g can you please provide a code sample for the same.

Comment: Please see the answer written below using Chain of Responsibility design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement using Chain of Responsibility design pattern:

```
    public abstract class Condition {

    private final boolean condition1;
    private final boolean condition2;
    private Condition next;

    public Condition(boolean condition1, boolean condition2) {
        this.condition1 = condition1;
        this.condition2 = condition2;
    }

    public void setNext(Condition next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public abstract void execute();

    public boolean isCondition1() {
        return condition1;
    }

    public boolean isCondition2() {
        return condition2;
    }

    public Condition getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

First implementation class of Condition

```
  public final class Condition12 extends Condition {

    public Condition12(boolean condition1, boolean condition2) {
        super(condition1, condition2);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (isCondition1() && isCondition2()) {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
        getNext().execute();
    }
}
```

Second implementation class of Condition

```
  public final class Condition23 extends Condition {

    public Condition23(boolean condition1, boolean condition2) {
        super(condition1, condition2);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (isCondition1() && isCondition2()) {
            System.out.println(2);
        }
        getNext().execute();
    }
}
```

Third implementation class of Condition

```
  public final class Condition34 extends Condition {

    public Condition34(boolean condition1, boolean condition2) {
        super(condition1, condition2);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (isCondition1() && isCondition2()) {
            System.out.println(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Test program

```
   public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Case1
        Condition condition12 = new Condition12(true, false);
        Condition condition23 = new Condition23(true, true);
        Condition condition34 = new Condition34(true, false);

        condition12.setNext(condition23);
        condition23.setNext(condition34);
        // Output is 2
        condition12.execute();

        //Case2
        condition23 = new Condition23(false, true);
        condition34 = new Condition34(true, true);

        condition12.setNext(condition23);
        condition23.setNext(condition34);
        // Output is 3
        condition12.execute();
    }
}
```

Let me know in case you have further questions.

Comment: @Dip90 If this solution works for you, please accept this answer. In case you feel some problem with the solution, please elaborate more on your requirement so that I can give some better solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can reduce the number of if statements, but the best to improve is the maintainability (since you expect more reward criteria).

Instead of 5 different reward functions, create a simple one and pass the criteria number. In that function you can split them again with a switch statement. This does not reduce the if's, but you have a single entry point, thus you can call the reward criteria in a for loop. Let the for loop return return the values in an array. Than you can combine the array values in a single number to find the final reward.

Like pseudo code:

```
class RewardWeight {
    public boolean checkReward(int number)
    {
        bool reward = False
        switch (number)
        {
        case 0: // 200th order
           // Logic or call function
        case 1: // Next
           ...
        }
        return reward
    }
```

Alternative 1:

```
    bool weights[MAX_REWARDS];

    public int getRewardWeight() {
        for (int reward = 0; reward < MAX_REWARDS; reward++) { 
            weights[reward] = checkReward(reward) ? 1 : 0;

        // Here you can  use all if statements for the conditions.
```

Alternative 2:

If you will have a really big list, you can put the combined factor in a single value, and make a big array that contains the weight factors:

```
    Rewards[] = { 1, 6, 3, 4, 6, ..., 25, 2, 3, 4, 3} // Means e.g.
        // Assuming there are 4 conditions, there are 16 values, the 5th value 
        // from the end
        // which is 0101 binary, means: condition 1 false, condition 2 true,
        // condition 3 false, condition 4 true has value 25.

    public int getRewardWeight() {
        for (int reward = 0; reward < MAX_REWARDS; reward++) { 
            weights += Power(2, reward) * checkReward(reward) ? 1 : 0;

        return Rewards[weights];
```

Note however, alternative 2 can result in a big array.